# How to make sure that the callback of jquery is being called upon

Tags: jquery, user-interface

How to make sure that the callback code is being called.

Make sure that the callback come before it hits the checking of gotMinPremium or gotMaxPremium.

I do not want to use the setTimeOut function.

The setTimeOut function cause the script to be always running. Any other method ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` call doesn't work because calling `setTimeout` doesn't prevent everything else after it from executing, it just registers a block of code to be run *at some point in the future* and then execution carries on with the code following `setTimeout` immediately.

Using deferred objects you can start both AJAX calls and wait for them both to complete before proceeding:

```
var getMin = $.post(...);
var getMax = $.post(...);

$.when(getMin, getMax).done(function(d1, d2) {
     // d1 and d2 will contain the result of the two AJAX calls
     MinPremium = d1.MinPremium;
     MaxPremium = d2.MaxPremium;

     ...
});
```

Note that this will *always* make both AJAX calls (and make them in parallel.  Alternatively:

```
$.post(...).done(function(data) {
    minPremium = data.MinPremium;

    // handle your minimum test here
    ...

    $.post(...).done(function(data) {
        maxPremium = data.MaxPremium;

        // handle maximum test here
        ...
    });
});
```

FWIW, is there any reason you can't have a single AJAX call return *both* values?